# I want to convert the timestamp in over 200000 rows after retriving them from sql server using LINQ. What is the optimized way to do that

Tags: linq, large-data, iqueryable

I am using Linq to retrive 1 year worth of data from sql server based on a ID. Then I have to iterate through all the rows and convert the Timestamp to epoch format but it is taking too long to do so. What is the optimized way of doing that?

```
dt = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-12);

var allData = obj.tableName.Where(m => m.AssetId == id&& m.CreatedDateTime > 
dt).OrderBy(m => m.CreatedDateTime);

foreach (var eachDataRow in allData){
   double date = ToUnixEpoch(eachDataRow.CreatedDateTime);
   //then save date in an array
}
```

The above sample code is doing eerything correctly but taking over 30 secs to finish the job. I have around 200000 data points.
Should I not use linq? what is the best way to do this?

Comment: NOT using LINQ would be the be more optimal. Instead of enumerating multiple times using LINQ, use one loop and continue on when conditions are not meant.

Comment: You can use TPL (task parallel library)

Comment: You could start with dropping the `OrderBy()`, if all you do is update single records at a time with no relation to each other then ordering is irrelevant.

Comment: If all you need is the CreatedDateTime, then you shouldn't be returning all columns from your table.

Comment: Could you please elaborate @ForeverZer0 ?

Comment: What is `obj` and `obj.tableName`?

Comment: obj is datacontext object @NetMage

Comment: If it is taking over 40 seconds to do `ToList`, then the problem is your SQL query takes that long. If you need all of `allData` columns then you need a faster infrastructure, or adding indexes to your database. You could look into `AsParallel` on your query and `Parallel.ForEach` - in some cases that can be faster.

Comment: What are you doing with this converted data? Are you saving it back to SQL Server? If so, avoid the needless code and data round trip and execute one `UPDATE` statement and get a 1000% performance boost.

Comment: I see from your comment below that this needs to be converted for display. Again you could use a database view or calculated column to define this in that database. This would remove the need convert in your App, but of course you'd still have to `ToList()` and that is probably the issue. Out of interest how long does `ToList()` alone take without the conversion? If it's quick I suggest you do it in the database.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid In the comments on the answer, it is stated "And if I convert that toList - it takes about 40 secs to do so" which makes me think the database query is the issue, and we don't have the information to help with that.

Comment: It's not clear to me whether the `ToList()` includes or excludes the conversion step. Perhaps the `IQueryable` part implies that but I'm not very advanced at C#. So I'm not sure. If it _doesn't_ include the epoch conversion, then an index (preferably clustered) on `CreatedDateTime` may help. If it _does_ include the epoch conversion then an index + conversion in the database may help, But it depends on the actual unfiltered table count

Answer (score 0):

Linq is for querying, not for working. System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel provides support for parallel loops and regions. I think this is what you're searching for:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IQueryable<MyClass> tmp = new List<MyClass>().AsQueryable<MyClass>();
    Parallel.ForEach(tmp, ConvertIfNeeded); // here the magic is happening. Put in your list and the method to be run
}

public class MyClass // some dummy-class to work with
{
    public DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
}

static readonly DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-12);
public static void ConvertIfNeeded(MyClass t) // static function to be used in out parallel work
{
    if (t.CreatedDateTime > dt)
        t.CreatedDateTime = ToUnitEpoch(t.CreatedDateTime);
}
```

[System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel@MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: The thing is I get an Iqueryable return from my query. And if I convert that toList - it takes about 40 secs to do so. So my question is what is the best way to retrive all the data in one go ?

Comment: @user3338877 Did you remove the `OrderBy`?

Comment: No, I need the data in ordered form to prepare an array for my graph on the view @NetMage

Comment: @user3338877 you can perform `Parallel.Foreach()` on a `IQueryable` but your problem ist that you don't know whats in the `IQuaryable`. The moment you start working on it, it is getting processed. Example: If you got a `IQueryable` from a Entity-Framework-DbContext, you don't even have data in your memory.

Comment: I think your problem is the `IQueryable`, not the `foreach`.